# Using of no delay mode in ncurses c++

Tags: c++, ncurses, curses

I'm doing console-based game using ncurses library. I'm using *getch()* to implement the movement of main charachter. Need to enable no delay mode to set non-blocking *getch()*.

```
nodelay(stdscr, TRUE);
```

But what if I want to use *getch()* or *getstr()* to read username before game start. Obviously I need to use *getch()* as usual, wait for user input. Something like this.

```
    Player player;
    char name[15];
    scr.add("Enter your name: ");
    getstr(name);
```

Is it possible to do? And can I use c++ std::string with ncurses and *gestr()* ? Because in Player class I'm working with std::string. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand your question, what is the problem?

Comment: @Stargateur thanks for your feedback, question was corrected. The problem is when I enable nodelay mode, first getch() (which I am using to read username) will become also non-blocking. And game starts immediately without waiting for input. Is there way to prevent it?

Comment: You can call `nodelay` any number of times at any point of your program and set it to either true or false at will. Read the username without nodelay, then run the game with nodelay.

Comment: @n.m. It helps, thanks. You can add your comment as an answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write nodelay(stdscr, FALSE); in your case just before the blocking code segment.
About std::string i would say yes you can because it is program memory and not the curses screen